# When I visit Shang Simla, the Sims 3 starts stuttering. What could cause this?

Tags: pc, technical-issues, the-sims-3

It only happens when i go to Shang Simla on a holliday, I've never had it since the start of the holiday and lowering graphics or reloading the game keeps the lag.

When I return home everything runs smooth again. Has anyone else had this problem and found a solution or a reason? I have all stuff and expansion packs installed.

Comment: Please explain "only happens during a holiday"?

Comment: i changed the question to make it clearer that it is an in game holiday location, in my case Shang Simla, the sims version of china. Sorry for that.

Comment: Holiday = Vacation: For Americans :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens to me too, and ONLY at Shang Simla, no other place... I read around and the common conclusion is that a sim out there got stuck and can't find a right pathing to get out so it keeps running a check to find a correct pathing to get out of the stuck condition, which is why the game lag every few min (game time)... which makes sense since there are quite a few spots there where a sim can get stuck with the horrible pathing.
I use http://ts3.tscexchange.com/index.php?topic=4685.0 which seems to help, but like any CC it probably has some risks too

Comment: thanks for the reply, i'll have to check and see if i can find this sim